# Docker exit witout throwing an error or executing code

Tags: java, docker, talend

I'm trying to run talend job inside a docker, build goes ok but when I run container it just exits without any error. Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM store/oracle/serverjre:8

ARG talend_job=export_data_xml

ENV TALEND_JOB ${talend_job}
ENV ARGS ""

WORKDIR /opt/talend

COPY  . /opt/talend

### Install Talend Job
RUN yum install -y unzip && \
    unzip ${TALEND_JOB}.zip && \
    rm -rf ${TALEND_JOB}.zip && \
    chmod +x ${TALEND_JOB}/${TALEND_JOB}_run.sh

VOLUME /data

CMD ["/bin/sh","-c","${TALEND_JOB}/${TALEND_JOB}_run.sh ${ARGS}"]
```

Run command:

```
docker run -it demo:latest
```

It doesn't execute a code or throw error. Any idea what can be wrong or how to debug it at least?

Thanks.

Comment: Execute the talend job in the server instead of docker image. Lets understand the issue, if its because of docker or talend job

Comment: I have tried it in linux server and it executes without problems.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess it would be that is a problem with the file paths.
You can debug it by running your image with:

```
docker run -ti demo:latest /bin/sh
```

In order to go inside the container, 
check if `export_data_xml_run.sh` is in the right path (`/opt/talend/export_data_xml`) and try to run it form there

Comment: it's on the right path, just check it, but when I run script from the container it also doesn't execute or throw error. I have tried to run same build script but from Power Shell and it runs just fine.

Comment: Maybe it is an os issue. If you are running the script in PowerShell I'm guessing you are using windows, and I think that the  "serverjre" image has a light linux os. You can try to run that job in a linux environment or to change that image.

Answer (score 0):

Some things worth a try:

Add some echo statements after each command, eg:

```
RUN echo "About to install unzip..." && yum install -y unzip && echo "unzip installed" \ 
...
```

If its failing here, you should at least see the echo statements.

Below, it looks like you're setting `pwd` to `/opt/talend`, then performing a COPY of whatever is in `pwd` to the same dir... effectively a null operation.

```
WORKDIR /opt/talend

COPY  . /opt/talend
```

This last line, be sure to pass the string args as individual strings. I've been working on something recently and the two strings I passed as `"command, input"` which was treated as a single string, rather than two individual strings (which is what I actually wanted):

```
CMD ["/bin/sh","-c","${TALEND_JOB}/${TALEND_JOB}_run.sh ${ARGS}"]
```

You could also log into the docker container to try and debug it once its running using:

```
docker exec -it [imageId] sh
```

Once inside the container you can run various commands to validate everything is as you expect it to be.

HTH

Comment: I did what you suggested, and RUN command executed smoothly, it does unzip. Also, tried to pass only zip folder in COPY command, but no help.

Comment: Are you aware you set `ARGS = ""` so the last line of your Dockerfile `CMD...` runs with an ARGS = ""... are you sure you didn't mean to use something else?

Comment: you are right, the problem was that I didn't pass this ARGS properly. Thank you.